# Copying data with different dates in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2012, duplicates

[image]I have a table with 4 columns and 8000 rows of data with a `datetime` column as 2016-01-05. I want to copy these 8000 rows of data to all the days of January from 1st to 31st.

Meaning, I should have 8000 * 31 days of data even though its the same data.

How do I do it without using an Excel document.

Comment: You would do this with a cross join. I would use a tally table to use for the cross join. select * from YourTable cross join TallyTable where TallyTable.Number <= 31. Without more details there isn't much more I can offer.

Comment: Thank you sir, what more details can I provide.? I have added the screenshot of my example data, please take a look. I have the first 3 columns and the last column DT in my table. SERV_LOC_NUM is my 8000 records for the date 2016-06-01. So now I need to copy the 1st 3 column data for 2016-06-02,2016-06-03 and so on, how do I create that incremental date column and copy these records.

Comment: I would keep the tally around. It can do so many things and will make your code a lot faster. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a temporary date table with values for each day in January 2016.

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMPDATE (DateCol DATETIME)

DECLARE @DAY INT = 1
DECLARE @DATE DATE = '2016-01-01'
WHILE @DAY <= 31
BEGIN
    INSERT #TEMPDATE
    VALUES (@DATE)
    SET @DAY +=1
    SET @DATE = DATEADD(DD,1,@DATE)
END
```

Next, you can `SELECT` desired columns and `CROSS JOIN` as others have said as well. Should get you the cartesian product between the two tables (8000 x 31 rows).

```
SELECT c.Column1, c.Column2, c.Column3, t.DateCol
FROM #TEMPDATE t
CROSS JOIN YourTableName c
```

Answer (score 2):

By creating a quick date sequence and cross joining your table to it you can update your table however you need to:

```
CREATE TABLE #t (c1 INT, c2 INT, c3 INT, c4 INT);

INSERT  INTO #t
VALUES  (10, 10, 10, 10),
        (20, 20, 20, 20);

;
WITH    CTE_Dates AS (
    SELECT TOP 31
            DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ao.object_id) - 1, '2016-01-01') AS Date
    FROM      sys.all_objects AS ao
)
SELECT  #t.c1,
        #t.c2,
        #t.c3,
        #t.c4,
        CTE_Dates.Date
FROM    #t
CROSS JOIN CTE_Dates;
```